# Facebook Android login, stuck on one account, even after logout

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement facebook login with my android app. Unfortunately, even after signing out. The app seems permanently stuck on one test account.

## How do I get it to sign in to a different account?

[image]

The following is the code that I have implemented in `MainActivity.java` and `activity_main.xml`

```
package com.example.www.facebook;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public LoginButton loginButton;
    public CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception)
            {
                // App code
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

And here we have the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.www.facebook.MainActivity">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: different account can you able to login in first time?

Comment: @sasikumar I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: apart from  test account  other account login or not?

Comment: @sasikumar I can't log out.